# Reloading only a div, many different possible links

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm very inexperienced in jQuery. I did some research and found that this code should allow me to reload only a div of my page:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".reload").click(function(){
    $("#day").load("/some_url #day > *");
  });
 });
</script>
```

As you can see I would like to reload only #day when an element of class .reload is clicked. My problem is with the URL. My page has many different instances of this class, each with a different url. They are generated in PHP as such:

```
echo "<div class=\"reload\"><a href=\"index.php?day=$day\" > $day </a></div>";
```

So I'm no longer sure I'm using the correct approach. Basically what I want is that when the user clicks one of those links, instead of reloading the whole page in that link, just update the #day on the current page. But each instance of the class reload points to a different link.

Comment: You could use the location.search DOM method to retrieve the data after the ?. How you would go about incorporating it into your code I am not sure because there isn't enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".reload a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).prop('href');
    $("#day").load(url + " #day > *");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLkVJ/)

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is right. You just need to figure out what url to open based on what item was clicked.

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".reload").click(function(){
             url = $(this).children('a').attr('href')
             $("#day").load(url);
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: It would be a lot better to handle the click event on the link, so that you can `preventDefault()`, or the page will change as well.

Comment: Thats true but maybe he wanted the div to be clickable. Depends on what his layout looks like basically.

Comment: There's nothing but a link in the div.  If you click the div it will go to the URL specified by the anchor, regardless of what a click event handler does.  It needs to stop that happening as well.